# Advanced text services - ink correction

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, input-languages

Out of blue it appeared two new keyboards in my language panel as you can see on this screenshot:

[image]

My operating system is Windows XP SP3. Whats weird this keyboard have been installed under all languages in my system (English & Slovak). What does it mean? Can I remove these new keyboards without any concern?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is a Windows feature that supports handwriting input devices.  Have you connected one?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371122(v=vs.85).aspx

If you don't use handwriting detection devices, then it's probably safe to remove it, but this was probably installed because of a plug-n-play that was inserted with handwriting input.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be something to do with handwriting recognition and is automatically slapped on when you add a new keyboard layout.

When I recently added Romanian layout my @/' key stopped responding, so I removed the new layout but that did not fix it

Only when I unchecked the Ink Correction did it start responding again. When I re-added the new layout, I made sure that Ink Correction was still unchecked and now both keyboard layouts work fine (there was, however, several weeks time-lag and much head-scratching involved and, in case you ever need them, ' is ascii 39 and @ is ascii 64)